# How to get all rows when using GROUP BY?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database like the following:

```
id | col_1 | col_2
------------------
1  |   a   |   x
2  |   a   |   x
3  |   b   |   x
4  |   b   |   z
5  |   c   |   x
```

I'm trying to get all rows that match col_2 = x plus the frequency of col_1, ordered by the frequency. For example, the output would be:

```
id | col_1 | col_2 | freq
-------------------------
1  |   a   |   x   |  2
2  |   a   |   x   |  2
3  |   b   |   x   |  1
5  |   c   |   x   |  1
```

I've tried various queries, but because I'm using a GROUP BY to get the frequency, I'm unable to get the individual rows (since I want each id). For example:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(col_1) AS freq
FROM mytable WHERE col_2 = x
GROUP BY col_1
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Unfortunately, this does not give me all the rows. It leaves out id = 2. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `freq` column looks like an independent, table-wide count of rows where `col_2 = 'x'`, grouped by `id`. You can get that using this query:

Here is SQL FIDDLE [DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7358e/4)

```
SELECT
  col_1,
  COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM myTable
WHERE col_2 = 'x'
GROUP BY col_1
```

Join it to a query for individual `id` values and you should get the results you're after:

```
SELECT
  id,
  col_1,
  col_2,
  col2Summary.freq
FROM myTable
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    col_1,
    COUNT(*) AS freq
  FROM myTable
  WHERE col_2 = 'x'
  GROUP BY col_1
) col2Summary ON myTable.col_1 = col2Summary.col_1
WHERE col_2 = 'x'
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Answer (score 1):

This is @EdGibbs solution rewritten using a Scalar Subquery. MySQL creates a different plan, you should test which is more efficient ([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/2dbf1/1)):

```
SELECT
  id,
  col_1,
  col_2,
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
   FROM myTable AS t2
   WHERE t.col_1 = t2.col_1
     AND col_2 = 'x') AS freq
FROM myTable AS t
WHERE col_2 = 'x'
ORDER BY freq DESC;
```

Btw, almost every other DBMS supports Windowed Aggregate Functions and then it would be a simple:

```
  COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY col_1) AS freq
```

Answer (score 0):

You need group by for col_2 too

Also remove the * and only include the GROUP BY columns

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, COUNT(*) AS freq
FROM mytable 
WHERE col_2 = x
GROUP BY col_1, col_2
ORDER BY freq DESC
```

Comment: @jeremytwfortune we dont know what OP need, maybe he need display the result in a grid. But yes you can have same count() result

Comment: OP clearly said that he wants `id` in the output. Your solution doesn't do it.

Comment: @jeremytwfortune, OP did provide desired output that clearly shows `id` and `count`. Together. That's the point. It is not just a simple `group by`.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to return any different results than the SQL statement I had? I am trying to get the id column as well, but I want id = 2 as well.

Comment: @VladimirBaranov Good call. Deleting my idiocy. =/